# MySql Record "corrupted" after a .net Update

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb6

I'm having the following problem after some research of two custom applications:

1.- Using my visual basic 6 application I set a date column of a registry with a "0000-00-00" value.

2.- Using my web application I update all data of the same registry (even all columns are updated, the value of the date column remains intact).

3.- When my visual basic 6 application tries to read the date column, it throws the following error:
Error Number => -2147217887
Error Description => Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.

In the web application I'm using the "Convert Zero Datetime=true" modifier in the connection to be able to read the "0000-00-00" value.
Why this registry looks like corrupted after that update? If I set that date column with the actual date in the web application, the visual basic 6 application doesn't have problem to read the values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you deliberately setting a zero-date value? Wouldn't leaving it `NULL` be a better plan?

Comment: I'd love to set a NULL value, but I can't have access to the Visual Basic 6 code, so I can't change that update. I want to know why this happens either.

Comment: If you can't change the code, it's not really your application. That's a pretty rough spot to be in.

Comment: Well, actually, it's our enterprise application that I can't modify because they doesn't allow me to change it. I want to know why this happens..., maybe can change the web application...